# How can I extend the x-axis on a Highcharts graph?

Tags: react-native, highcharts

I have a Highcharts bar graph. Each point has a group of results, however the first and last element are being cropped. How can I extend the x-axis so every bar is shown?

In the image below each group has the same results so you can see the N and P are dropped from the first group and S and Mg from the last grouping.

[image]

The data is coming from a database, so i don't know how many groups there will be, or what range (so simply adding a day to each end is not sufficient, the overlap could be larger or smaller)

```
  const conf = {
      chart: {
        type: "column",
        animation: false,
        marginRight: 10,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/YYYY"
      },
      title: {
        text: "Spread Events"
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: "datetime",
        tickPixelInterval: 50
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: "Spread"
        },
        plotLines: [
          {
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: "#808080"
          }
        ]
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: true
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: false
      },
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          pointPadding: 0.2,
          borderWidth: 0
        }
      },
      series: this.state.graphData
    };
```

and this is the `graphData` from the example

```
[
  {
    "name": "N",
    "data": [[1559669642443, 300], [1559343600000, 300], [1559257200000, 300]]
  },
  {
    "name": "P",
    "data": [[1559669642443, 160], [1559343600000, 160], [1559257200000, 160]]
  },
  {
    "name": "K",
    "data": [[1559669642443, 470], [1559343600000, 470], [1559257200000, 470]]
  },
  {
    "name": "S",
    "data": [[1559669642443, 120], [1559343600000, 120], [1559257200000, 120]]
  },
  {
    "name": "Mg",
    "data": [[1559669642443, 90], [1559343600000, 90], [1559257200000, 90]]
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi @Loofer, Could you provide us with your chart configuration object? In this similar example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/twz1p0so/ everything works fine.

Comment: hmm using that fiddle thing it works http://jsfiddle.net/6p8kocex/1/ I guess it is something in the react-native complexity that is breaking it... as ever!

Comment: Tho this simple view does show 'my' behaviour http://jsfiddle.net/gxjk98zL/2/  (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [Highcharts error #15](https://www.highcharts.com/errors/15/) in a console, which means that your data is not sorted. Highcharts requires sorted data in ascending X order:

```
series: [{
        ...,
        data: [
            [1559257200000, 300],
            [1559343600000, 300],
            [1559669642443, 300]
        ]
    }, ...
]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y2rzd65m/